# Make column span all rows (including implicit) in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a grid column span *every* row, including implicit rows.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052336/make-css-grid-item-span-from-first-to-last-row/44052563#) asking how to span all grid rows. The second answer has a correction stating a better solution. This seems like it would work, but my own example, and the comments on the second answer, indicate that it doesn't work.

The [W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#overview-placement) gives this a very close example as well.

Is there something wrong with my code, or is this possibly a bug in Firefox, Chrome, *and* Safari?

[I also have this example in a CodePen here](https://codepen.io/freshyill/pen/dVgZrr?editors=1100).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr 300px;
  /* grid-template-rows: repeat(auto) [rows-end]; Doesn't seem to help */
  /* grid-template-rows: [rows-start] repeat(auto) [rows-end]; Doesn't seem to help */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  /*   justify-items: stretch; */
  /*   align-items: stretch; */
}

.container>* {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid #666;
}

.pop {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  /* grid-column: 1 / -1; If I switch to this, this div will span the full width of the grid, which is exactly what I'm trying to do with rows*/
}

.tertiary {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.secondary {
  grid-column: 3 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  /* Doesn't work */
  /* grid-row: rows-start / rows-end; Doesn't work */
  /* grid-row: 1 / rows-end; Also doesn't work */
  /* grid-row: 1 / span 7; This works, but I need to span an unknown number of rows*/
  /* grid-row: 1 / span 99; This is gross and creates 99 rows */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="secondary">Secondary - why doesn't this span all the way to the bottom of the grid?</div>
  <div class="tertiary">Tertiary</div>
  <div class="tertiary">Tertiary</div>
  <div class="tertiary">Tertiary</div>
  <div>Primary</div>
  <div>Primary</div>
  <div>Primary</div>
  <div class="pop">Span tertiary and primary</div>
  <div>Primary</div>
  <div class="tertiary">Tertiary</div>
  <div>Primary</div>
  <div>Primary</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two obstacles in your way.

First, this line of CSS code in your `.container` rule:

```css
grid-template-rows: repeat(auto);
```

This code is invalid. The argument in the `repeat()` notation must begin with a positive integer, which specifies the number of repetitions. You don't have that, so the code doesn't work. More details in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#repeat-syntax).

Second, even if the code above was correct, let's say:

```css
grid-auto-rows: auto; (which happens to be the default setting anyway)
```

Your column would still not span all rows.

This is because, as you may have seen in [the other answer you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44052336/3597276), a track definition can be set to cover all perpendicular tracks *only in the explicit grid*.

So this would work:

```css
grid-template-rows: repeat(6, auto);
```

[revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGeZxo?editors=1100)

The rest of the problem is covered in detail in [the other answer you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44052336/3597276).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the invalid rows code. So I'm back to my actual original need—is there a way to make the third column span all the way to the bottom when there is an *unknown* number of rows?

Comment: Yeah, that question was explored in the other post. That's the best the community has come up with so far using pure CSS. There doesn't appear to be a clean method for this in Grid layout.

Comment: Alternatively, you can target the grid items directly: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46308048/3597276