# Is there a way to select items in css grids such as 'grid-column' and change the style using javascript DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, grid

I want to select a grid item and target the `grid-column` style that I have in my CSS. I want to actively change it using javascript but I have no idea how to select it with the DOM.

I figured I could use something like

```js
document.querySelector('.className').style.grid-column = '1 / 2';
```

but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Adding your code would make it a lot easier to help with this question.

Comment: would be `style.gridColumn`

Comment: I actually just figured that out myself as well, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426901), you could try something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.className[style*="grid-column: 1 / 2"]');
```

However, it's a fragile solution.