# Targeting the first item on each line in a multiline flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a multiline flexbox container `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap`. How can I apply a style or css class to the first item on each line?

The only thing I can come up with is to use Javascript to iterate over the items and manually apply/remove classes. I'd really like a pure css solution though.

I don't know how many items will be in the flex box ahead of time, or what their widths will end up being.

Comment: Yea you're gonna have to go with the javascript solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible with CSS.

Targeting the first item in each line of a multiline flex container, when the number of items in each line is unpredictable, is beyond the capabilities of CSS, because the first item in each line is arbitrary. It may be any item that places first.

At best, CSS can match a definite pattern. Without a pattern you'll need another technology.

Try JavaScript.

CSS Grid Layout has the same limitation:

- [How to target a specific column or row in CSS Grid Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46308048/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Found this trying to space my elements consistently without any leftMargining on the first or rightMargining on the last elements in a row `gap:10px` did the trick if that's what you're after.