# Is there a way to snake/queue the flow of items in a CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

#### Default behavior:

`|A|B|C|D|
 |E|F|G|H|
 |I|J|K|L|`

#### Desired behavior:

`|A|B|C|D|
 |H|G|F|E|
 |I|J|K|L|`

I've looked into the `grid-auto-flow` property as well as the `direction` property but there seems to be no workaround without resorting to javascript. Is there a way to achieve this with CSS?

Comment: no there no *snake* feature on CSS for this

Comment: There is a duplicate question dealing with the sameoffering some workarounds but I am not able to find it ...

Comment: If it is about a four column grid, then nth-child is your friend https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zQXBwP , else, javascript will be required to set this method according to column's number  on the fly

Comment: You should really post more details and code in your question. As it stands, this question is very broad.

Comment: Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/Birdlaw/doyr8vx2/. One workaround I was thinking of would involve selecting every other row and applying the `direction: rtl;` property. Unfortunately it looks like we can't yet select rows https://stackoverflow.com/q/46308048.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `flex` properties and `nth-child` selector

```html
<div class="snakeContainer">
  <div>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>B</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>D</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>E</span>
    <span>F</span>
    <span>G</span>
    <span>H</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>J</span>
    <span>K</span>
    <span>L</span>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.snakeContainer div:nth-child(even){
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.snakeContainer div:nth-child(odd){
  display: flex;
}
</style>
```