# CSS GRID: want to put border after each row

Tags: html, css, css-grid, border

I have a problem, I want to put some border after each row but I dont know how to do this, could you help me please (without add 26 div)

```css
.events {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(26, 30px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: var(--calBgColor);
}
```

```html
<div class="day mon">
  <div class="date">
    <p class="date-num">9</p>
    <p class="date-day">Mon</p>
  </div>
  <div class="events">
    <a href="http://google.com" class="event start-2 end-5 securities">
      <p class="title">Securities Regulation</p>
      <p class="time">2 PM - 5 PM</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want this (with black line) :

[image]

thanks guys

Comment: I don't know if this is of any use, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56900389/css-grid-how-to-add-line-between-rows).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Well, adding border in your case you can use `border-bottom` property, but since you're using the `.events` class to define the grid rows, you might want to apply the border to the child elements of `.events`, but again since you don't want to add 26 divs, good approach would be targeting children of the `.events` class, your mentioned HTML structure is showing that each event is contained within an `<a>` tag, which is again inside the `.events` `div`, I'd do it like this:

```
.events a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
    display: block;
}

.events a:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Also, this assumes that each row in your grid corresponds to an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

When I have personally coded these before I do include the individual divs due to the amount of content placed in, but this is exactly what you aren't asking for though.

If you are looking for a simple solution and you have a fixed height for each day/using absolute for your events (which appears you are), you could use a background image of the dotted lines.

```css
.calendar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.day {
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
    width: calc(20% - 1rem);
}
.day-title {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}
.day-timeslot-container {
    height: 910px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvZPA.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
.event {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
    background-color: rgba(203, 255, 192, 0.7);
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: calc(100% - 0.5rem);
    color: #000;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/*  Note: 
    * the start/length times are in 30m intervals b/c I didn't know your system and it's what I have personally done in the past
    * 35px = 30m in my example
*/
/* would start at 00:00am */
.start-0 {
    top: 0;
}
/* would start at 00:30am */
.start-1 {
    top: 35px;
}
/* would start at 01:00am */
.start-2 {
    top: 70px;
}
/* would start at 01:30am */
.start-3 {
    top: 105px;
}
/* would start at 05:00am */
.start-10 {
    top: 350px;
}

/* would run for 30m */
.length-30 {
    height: 35px;
}
/* would run for 60m */
.length-60 {
    height: 70px;
}
/* would run for 90m */
.length-90 {
    height: 105px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="calendar">
            <div class="day">
                <p class="day-title"><strong>9</strong> Mon</p>
                <div class="day-timeslot-container">
                    <a href="http://google.com" class="event start-2 length-90 securities">
                        <strong>Securities Regulation</strong>
                        <span>2 PM - 5 PM</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="day">
                <p class="day-title"><strong>10</strong> Tue</p>
                <div class="day-timeslot-container">
                    <a href="http://google.com" class="event start-10 length-60 securities">
                        <strong>Securities Regulation</strong>
                        <span>2 PM - 5 PM</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="day">
                <p class="day-title"><strong>11</strong> Wed</p>
                <div class="day-timeslot-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="day">
                <p class="day-title"><strong>12</strong> Thr</p>
                <div class="day-timeslot-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="day">
                <p class="day-title"><strong>13</strong> Fri</p>
                <div class="day-timeslot-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[bg image for hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvZPA.png)