# Apply rules to all nodes in the same level, except the ones in the last row

Tags: css

I know the title of the question is kinda confusing, so I will try to explain better what I want to say.

Let's say that I have a group of elements, like a grid.
- This grid can be uneven
- This grid can have any number of columns

This is an example of a grid of 3 columns, with 7 elements.

[image]

As you see I am drawing a line below some of the elements.

What I would like is to apply these styles to all elements, except the ones on the last row. No matter how many items this may contain.

How can I achieve this?

The markup is really as simple as you can imagine:

```html
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

What I have right now is:

```
.item:nth-child(n + 4){
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: What does your existing CSS look like? Post a [mcve] please

Comment: That just looks like a border top for all items

Comment: Added the CSS I have

Comment: Dynamically, no - layout models like flexbox and grid don't provide a mechanism to select specific rows or columns. You would have to know beforehand how many columns you have. There are [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308048/how-to-target-a-specific-column-or-row-in-css-grid-layout) that provide more context (and possible workarounds)

Answer (score 1):

Since most approaches have already been shown out there, I will leave a hacky solution.

You can use a pseudo-element with `position: absolute` in the last item that will cover the whole horizontal width in bottom. The `position: relative` will be in the parent element.

```
.items {
  position: relative;
}
.item:last-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will not remove the borders, but hide them. It only works if the background is a solid color.