# CSS select row element on grid

Tags: css

What's the best way to select the specific items in a row?

For example, let's make the div`.test` which index are odd to be `background-color: red;` on odd row, and div`.test` which index are even to be `background-color: blue;` on even row.

I can hard code it like my example below, but is there any better way of doing this?

The reason I don't use `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` is that the styling of **odd items** in **odd row** is different from **even items** in **even row**. You will get the idea of running the code snippet...

```css
#ct {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.test {
  height: 100px;
}

.test:nth-child(1),
.test:nth-child(3),
.test:nth-child(6),
.test:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: red;
}

.test:nth-child(2),
.test:nth-child(4),
.test:nth-child(5),
.test:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="ct">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to target a specific column or row in CSS Grid Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308048/how-to-target-a-specific-column-or-row-in-css-grid-layout)

Comment: @DanielA.White Greeting, I'm afraid it's not relevant because my question is different if you read it...I'll edit my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution by changing the html structure a little bit.

**Important Note: This will only work if you could have ability to change html structure.**

```css
#ct {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.test {
  height: 100px;
}

#ct:nth-child(odd)>.test:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red
}

#ct:nth-child(odd)>.test:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue
}

#ct:nth-child(even)>.test:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue
}

#ct:nth-child(even)>.test:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="ct">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
<div id="ct">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

P.S.: This seems longer and more mess than your code, but it will be much easier and shorter than your code if you have a lot of them (grid).

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea is to use [display: contents;](https://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout#using_display_contents) like in example below:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
.row {
  display: contents;
}
.row:nth-child(2n+1) div {
  background: CadetBlue;
}
.row:nth-child(2n+2) div {
  background: DarkCyan ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>five</div>
      <div>six</div>
      <div>seven</div>
      <div>eight</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>five</div>
      <div>six</div>
      <div>seven</div>
     <div>eight</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>five</div>
      <div>six</div>
      <div>seven</div>
      <div>eight</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```