# Remove right border from the last row items

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a 3 rows list of items. I need to divide first and second row by a borders, so I add right border to the items but I do not need borders for the items from the third row.

```css
.test-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.test-row-item {
  padding-bottom: 3.2rem;
  border-right-color: #2C327A;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-row">
  <div class="test-row-item">
    1
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    2
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    3
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    4
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    5
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    6
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    9
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to target a specific column or row in CSS Grid Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308048/how-to-target-a-specific-column-or-row-in-css-grid-layout)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case use a second CSS rule that *removes* the right-border starting from the 7th instance, using the selector `.test-row-item:nth-child(n+7)`:

```css
.test-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.test-row-item {
  padding-bottom: 3.2rem;
  border-right-color: #2C327A;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-style: solid;
}

.test-row-item:nth-child(n+7) {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-row">
  <div class="test-row-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    9
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.test-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.test-row-item:nth-child(n + 4) {
  padding-bottom: 3.2rem;
  border-left-color: #2C327A;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-row">
  <div class="test-row-item">
    1
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    2
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    3
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    4
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    5
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    6
  </div>
   <div class="test-row-item">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="test-row-item">
    9
  </div>
  
</div>
```