Can I target a css grid-auto-flow: dense element by position?
When you lay a number of dynamic elements out with display: grid it's often desirable to let the browser shuffle the elements a little to fill the gaps in the grid using grid-auto-flow: dense.
Once you've done this - is there any sensible way to target the elements - not based on their position in the markup but based on their position on the page?
Consider this demo at the top of the docs on MDN.
How can I target Three and Four because they're the last in the row... not because they're 3rd & 4th in the markup... such that, should the layout change (because the size of One changes, for instance) I'm then targeting whatever else is last on the row?
I think it's impossible (without Javascript).  Is that true?


https://stackoverflow.com/a/69838781/8620333 (possible but in a far future)

please read the answer I linked as comment before editing your question saying it's not a duplicate.

Thanks @TemaniAfif - the link to your specific response (sorry - missed first time) is helpful. Might I suggest that given the 'duplicate' question isn't asking the same thing as I am (about dense, unpredictable layouts) and how hard it is to find your answer (I've been looking for months) .. that this is left up for others. I'm happy to answer my own question citing your source if that helps.

no need to add a new answer citing my answer. That's what duplicate is for. Your answer is within the duplicate question so no no need for a new answer (and an edit saying it's not a duplicate)

... but your answer can only be found by someone getting so frustrated as to take the time to ask the question ... only to be told it's a duplicate. That's not helpful. No-one, having my problem, is going to stumble across your answer ... because the question is different. There are numerous legitimate answers to the other question.  The answer to my question is "not possible without javascript". They are not duplicates. Perhaps you misunderstand the other question?

to be told it's a duplicate --> "duplicate" is not a bad thing or a punishment. It's a way to answer questions. Your question is now linked to the duplicate that contains the answer and everyone will know this by seeing your question. Also duplicates don't mean exact questions. It means (as you can read in the banner) "This question already has answers here:"

I don't care about being punished - that's not my point. My issue is that marking it as a duplicate is obfuscative - which goes against the purpose of this site.
The duplicate question is asking about targeting a predictable layout. The valid answers describe reframing the problem mathematically. There are solutions.
My question is about a non-determinative grid layout - for which there is no pure-css solution (yet, as you point out).
By redirecting my question you make it very hard for others with my question to find the answer - because they're not actually duplicate questions.

from the duplicate question: I have tried nth-child selectors on the div elements, but this does not allow me to specify row or column when the items are automatically placed by the CSS grid layout engine. --> There is no mention for any predictable layout. The layout used in the question is an example but the question is a generic question asking how to target rows and columns which is the same as your question, hence it's a duplicate (regardless the answers and their content)

You're missing the point. The questions are different - and tbh, your answer to their question seems to miss what their asking too - so there's obviously nothing more I can do.
Nevertheless, marking my question as duplicate (whether you like to admit it or not) is unhelpful to anyone else who needs to solve the specific problem I'm trying to solve.
I'm not sure why you're intent on being unhelpful. Leaving my question up, with a proper response, harms no-one and helps everyone who has my specific, ostensibly unanswered question.  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

I have been thinking this issue over as well. What is the best approach when two different questions could be answered by the same answer? I realise that you disagree over whether this particular question is in fact a duplicate. Let's assume that the question is not a duplicate, and it could be answered by an existing answer to a different question. It would be nice if SO allowed you to create an answer which is simply a reference to an existing answer. That way at least you get a direct path to the particular answer ... marking a question as a dupe requires someone to read ALL its answers.

Thanks @BrettDonald. I'm at a bit of a loss too.  I've solved my challenge (with a few lines of .js) so it's not an issue for me anymore ... but having spent time hunting .. and spoken with a few folk on Twitter (who's blogs on the subject I found in my travels) I'm pretty sure there are others hunting for the answer to this specific question which they're not going to find.  Hey ho. :shrugs: Take care.
